# Line after a paragraph with an image

Tags: html, css

I have a paragraph with an image aligned to the left and a description to the right. The image is higher than the text. Here is an example:

[image]

Now, how can I make sure that the next paragraph starts below the image? Is it possible without putting several `<br>` before the next paragraph?

I tried putting an image inside `<p>` tags, `<div>` tags. This should be pretty straightforward, but I can't figure it out.

Comment: hey can you add your code here to better understand and give results...

Comment: You can try putting both the image and the text on the right inside a div element

Comment: try floating your image (to the left) and use `clear:left` for your next paragraph.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To achieve the result you want to use, you need to use `float:left` on image. This makes image just float on the left side while all the text  flowing next to it. When you want next element to not flow around the image you need to clear the float. There are many ways clear the float but the simplest is just `clear:both`. Here's [very good article](http://css-tricks.com/all-about-floats/) that describes this in more details.

Here's sample HTML code. You can play around with it at http://jsbin.com/qilup/1/edit.

```
<html>
<body>
  <div>
    <img style="float:left" src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/d/de/POL_apple.jpg" width=100px height=100px/> 
    Jar jar bins loves lits of apples! Jar jar bins loves lits of apples! Jar jar bins loves lits of apples! Jar jar bins loves lits of apples!
  </div>
  <div style="clear:both"/>
  <p>
    <strong>Next Paragraph is here</strong>  
  </p>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<div id="upperdiv"><img src="yoursourcename"/><p>Eat fruits.....not kidding!</p></div>
<div id="lowerdiv">next paragraph.....</div>
```

Automatically your next paragraph should start in lower div now.

Answer (score 1):

Check this [demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/kLlCe).

you need to wrap the `<p>` inside and `<div>` and target the `p:first-child`.